# ORMLite error no databasefield annotations exists

Tags: java, android, annotations, ormlite

I have this error when I run my Android application:

> No fields have a DatabaseField
>   annotation in class [[Lmodel.Vak;

My class Vak has annotations, so I really don't understand why it still giving me this error.

```
package model;
import com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField;
import com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTable;
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "vak")
public class Vak {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = "vakID", id=true) Long id;
    @DatabaseField int rij;
    @DatabaseField
    int kolom;
...
}
```

I have a file called Databasehelper.java in which extends OrmLiteSqLiteOpenHelper and the file looks like this:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {
// name of the database file for your application -- change to something
// appropriate for your app
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "project56.db";
// any time you make changes to your database objects, you may have to
// increase the database version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

private DatabaseType databaseType = new SqliteAndroidDatabaseType();

// the DAO object we use to access the tables
private Dao<Vleugel, Long> vleugelDao = null;
private Dao<Verdieping, Long> verdiepingDao = null;
private Dao<NavigatiePunt, Long> navigatiePuntDao = null;
private Dao<Lokaal, Long> lokaalDao = null;
private Dao<Raster, Long> rasterDao = null;
private Dao<Vak, Long> vakDao = null;
private Dao<Graaf, Long> graafDao = null;
private Dao<Vertex, Long> vertexDao = null;
private Dao<Edge, Long> edgeDao = null;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

/**
 * This is called when the database is first created. Usually you should
 * call createTable statements here to create the tables that will store
 * your data.
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
    try {
        Log.i(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "onCreate");
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Vleugel.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Verdieping.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, NavigatiePunt.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Lokaal.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Raster.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Vak.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Graaf.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Vertex.class);
        TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Edge.class);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Can't create database", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

/**
 * This is called when your application is upgraded and it has a higher
 * version number. This allows you to adjust the various data to match the
 * new version number.
 */
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource,
        int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    try {
        Log.i(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "onUpgrade");
        TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Vleugel.class, true);
        TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Verdieping.class, true);
        TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, NavigatiePunt.class, true);
        TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Lokaal.class, true);
        TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Raster.class, true);
        TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Vak.class, true);
        TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Graaf.class, true);
        TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Vertex.class, true);
        TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Edge.class, true);

        // after we drop the old databases, we create the new ones
        onCreate(db, connectionSource);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(DatabaseHelper.class.getName(), "Can't drop databases", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the Database Access Object (DAO) for the classes It will create
 * it or just give the cached value.
 */
public Dao<Vleugel, Long> getVleugelDao() throws SQLException {
    if (vleugelDao == null) {
        vleugelDao = getDao(Vleugel.class);
    }
    return vleugelDao;
}

public Dao<Verdieping, Long> getVerdiepingDao() throws SQLException {
    if (verdiepingDao == null) {
        verdiepingDao = getDao(Verdieping.class);
    }
    return verdiepingDao;
}

public Dao<NavigatiePunt, Long> getNavigatiePuntDao() throws SQLException {
    if (navigatiePuntDao == null) {
        navigatiePuntDao = getDao(NavigatiePunt.class);
    }
    return navigatiePuntDao;
}

public Dao<Lokaal, Long> getLokaalDao() throws SQLException {
    if (lokaalDao == null) {
        lokaalDao = getDao(Lokaal.class);
    }
    return lokaalDao;
}

public Dao<Raster, Long> getRasterDao() throws SQLException {
    if (rasterDao == null) {
        rasterDao = getDao(Raster.class);
    }
    return rasterDao;
}

public Dao<Vak, Long> getVakDao() throws SQLException {
    if (vakDao == null) {
        vakDao = getDao(Vak.class);
    }
    return vakDao;
}

public Dao<Graaf, Long> getGraafDao() throws SQLException {
    if (graafDao == null) {
        graafDao = getDao(Graaf.class);
    }
    return graafDao;
}

public Dao<Vertex, Long> getVertexDao() throws SQLException {
    if (vertexDao == null) {
        vertexDao = getDao(Vertex.class);
    }
    return vertexDao;
}

public Dao<Edge, Long> getEdgeDao() throws SQLException {
    if (edgeDao == null) {
        edgeDao = getDao(Edge.class);
    }
    return edgeDao;
}

/**
 * Close the database connections and clear any cached DAOs.
 */
@Override
public void close() {
    super.close();
    vleugelDao = null;
    verdiepingDao = null;
    navigatiePuntDao = null;
    lokaalDao = null;
    rasterDao = null;
    vakDao = null;
    graafDao = null;
    vertexDao = null;
    edgeDao = null;
}
}
```

I also have a file Controller which extends OrmLiteBaseActivity:

```
public class Controller extends OrmLiteBaseActivity<DatabaseHelper> {

Dao<Vleugel, Long> vleugelDao;
Dao<Verdieping, Long> verdiepingDao;
Dao<NavigatiePunt, Long> navigatiePuntDao;
Dao<Lokaal, Long> lokaalDao;
Dao<Raster, Long> rasterDao;
Dao<Graaf, Long> graafDao;
Dao<Vertex, Long> vertexDao;
Dao<Edge, Long> edgeDao;
Dao<Vak, Long> vakDao;

// Databasehelper is benodigd voor ORMLite
static {
    OpenHelperManager.setOpenHelperFactory(new SqliteOpenHelperFactory() {
        public OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper getHelper(Context context) {
            return new DatabaseHelper(context);
        }
    });
}

public Controller() throws SQLException {
    /** initialiseren van dao */
    vleugelDao = getHelper().getVleugelDao();
    verdiepingDao = getHelper().getVerdiepingDao();
    navigatiePuntDao = getHelper().getNavigatiePuntDao();
    lokaalDao = getHelper().getLokaalDao();
    rasterDao = getHelper().getRasterDao();
    graafDao = getHelper().getGraafDao();
    vertexDao = getHelper().getVertexDao();
    edgeDao = getHelper().getEdgeDao();
    vakDao = getHelper().getVakDao();
}

/**
 * Haalt vleugel idNaam op uit dao object bijv. K1
 * 
 * @return Vleugel
 * @throws java.sql.SQLException
 */

public Vleugel getVleugel(String vleugelIDNaam)
        throws java.sql.SQLException {
    // select * from vleugel where idNaam='{vleugelIDNaam}'
    QueryBuilder<Vleugel, Long> qb = vleugelDao.queryBuilder();
    Where where = qb.where();
    // the name field must be equal to "foo"
    where.eq("idNaam", vleugelIDNaam);
    PreparedQuery<Vleugel> preparedQuery = qb.prepare();
    List<Vleugel> vleugelList = vleugelDao.query(preparedQuery);
    Log.v("Getvleugel", vleugelList.size() + "");
    if (vleugelList.size() == 1) {
        return vleugelList.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}

public Verdieping getVerdieping(int nummer) throws java.sql.SQLException {
    // TODO: Met querybuilder query naar db om verdieping te pakken
    return null;
}

/**
 * Haalt navigatiepunt op
 * 
 * @param naam
 * @return
 * @throws java.sql.SQLException
 */
public NavigatiePunt getNavigatiePunt(String naam)
        throws java.sql.SQLException {
    // select * from navigatiepunt where naam='{naam}'
    QueryBuilder<NavigatiePunt, Long> qb = navigatiePuntDao.queryBuilder();
    Where where = qb.where();
    where.eq("naam", naam);
    PreparedQuery<NavigatiePunt> preparedQuery = qb.prepare();
    List<NavigatiePunt> navigatieList = navigatiePuntDao
            .query(preparedQuery);
    Log.v("GetLokaal", navigatieList.size() + "");
    if (navigatieList.size() == 1) {
        return navigatieList.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Get lokaal object op basis van lokaalcode
 * 
 * @param lokaalcode
 * @return
 * @throws java.sql.SQLException
 */
public Lokaal getLokaal(String lokaalcode) throws java.sql.SQLException {
    // select * from lokaal where lokaalcode='{lokaalcode}'
    QueryBuilder<Lokaal, Long> qb = lokaalDao.queryBuilder();
    Where where = qb.where();
    where.eq("lokaalcode", lokaalcode);
    PreparedQuery<Lokaal> preparedQuery = qb.prepare();
    List<Lokaal> lokaalList = lokaalDao.query(preparedQuery);
    Log.v("GetLokaal", lokaalList.size() + "");
    if (lokaalList.size() == 1) {
        return lokaalList.get(0);
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

So do you have any advice on this, what should I check?

Comment: `@DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = "vakID", id=true) Long id;` As far as I know you could either use generatedId or id, but not both at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug in ORMLite around foreign object loops that was fixed in version 4.22.  ORMLite was not properly handing the case where A has a foreign-field B which has a foreign-field to C which has a foreign-field back to A..

> http://ormlite.com/releases/

Please send me some direct mail @Yanny if this does or doesn't work and I will tune this answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Could you check, are created table Vak in your DB? The absence of this table can be reason of this crash.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably late for giving solution but this is my solution:
you see proguard try to obfuscating the code and if you read proguard in depth or intro

```
http://proguard.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html
```

what Shrinking in proguard ->  Shrinking programs such as ProGuard can analyze bytecode and remove unused classes, fields, and methods.
so from this we can presume that it is removing your objects since it's not used by anywhere...

so wt you probably need?
you need to stop proguard from shirking that methods or objects from process
so this is the line for that..:
`-keep class com.j256.**<br>
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }<br>
-keep enum com.j256.**<br>
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }<br>
-keep interface com.j256.**<br>
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }`


this line will keep proguard from removing my public methods and variables..
`-keepclassmembers class classpath.** {
  public *;
}`

you need to write column name for atlest id... because it will search for it and will proguard change it's name... so you need to define column name id for primary key..