# ORMLite error: No fields have a DatabaseField annotation in class java.lang.Character

Tags: android, ormlite

I use 4.46 version of core ORMLite and Android, and I have this issue all time.

**Foo class**

```
@DatabaseTable
public class Foo {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    public int id;
    @DatabaseField(index = true)
    public String title;
    @ForeignCollectionField
    ForeignCollection<Foo2> foo2s;

    public Foo() {
        // needed by ormlite
    }

}
```

**Foo2 class**

```
@DatabaseTable
public class Foo2 {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    public int id;
    @DatabaseField
    public Date date;

    public Foo2() {
        // needed by ormlite
    }
}
```

**ORMLiteFragment** (I need invoke getHelper() from Fragment)

```
public class OrmLiteFragment extends Fragment {

    private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = null;

    protected DatabaseHelper getHelper() {
        if (databaseHelper == null) {
            databaseHelper =
                OpenHelperManager.getHelper(getActivity(), DatabaseHelper.class);
        }
        return databaseHelper;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (databaseHelper != null) {
            OpenHelperManager.releaseHelper();
            databaseHelper = null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    /**
    * Some methods non important for this...
    */

    public static class SectionFragment extends OrmLiteFragment { 
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            // Some code....

            getHelper().getFoo2RuntimeDao(); // HERE FIRES THE ERROR!

            // Some code....
        }
    }
}
```

The DatabaseHelper class is the same than [Android examples code page](http://ormlite.com/android/examples/) but with Foo2RuntimeDao() and Foo1RuntimeDao()

**Issue**

```
09-03 14:27:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(557): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-03 14:27:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(557): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No fields have a DatabaseField annotation in class java.lang.Character
09-03 14:27:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTableConfig.extractFieldTypes(DatabaseTableConfig.java:215)
09-03 14:27:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTableConfig.fromClass(DatabaseTableConfig.java:146)
09-03 14:27:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at com.j256.ormlite.table.TableInfo.<init>(TableInfo.java:53)
09-03 14:27:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.initialize(BaseDaoImpl.java:149)
09-03 14:27:15.756: E/AndroidRuntime(557):  at com.j256.ormlite.dao.BaseDaoImpl.<init>(BaseDaoImpl.java:126)
```

### - Update 1

If I try get a [queryForAll()](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#queryForAll%28%29) (return a List) and I didn't save data previously I get a NullPointerException instead of an empty List or null. Like this:

```
public class MainActivity2 extends OrmLiteBaseActivity<DatabaseHelper> {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getHelper().getChapterRunDao();   //This Works!
        getHelper().getChapterRunDao().queryForAll();  //This throws NullPointerException
    }
}
```

**Issue**

```
09-04 15:32:13.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3615): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-04 15:32:13.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3615): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.emanga/com.emanga.ORMLite}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-04 15:32:13.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
09-04 15:32:13.261: E/AndroidRuntime(3615):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I'm using ormlite 4.41. All was working well earlier - the change that I have done is introduced proguard into the mix. Are you using proguard too?

Comment: I don't use proguard. I think the root of the problem come when tables are generated. The table of Foo model for some reason it didn't creates. I am researching why this happens.

Comment: I see. My problem was due to proguard. I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I think it was a problem with [DatabaseConfigUtil](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_4.html#Use-With-Android). For some unknown reason the file that it generated in the raw folder with the aim to improve the performance in Android wasn't update correctly.

This only happens when I run the class from Eclipse, if I do from terminal all works fine. I don't know why this odd behavior. Now I always run it from the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

if you have no field error this will help
my answer from here: [ORMLite error no databasefield annotations exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856905/ormlite-error-no-databasefield-annotations-exists/35057195#35057195)

It's probably late for giving solution but this is my solution:
you see proguard try to obfuscating the code and if you read proguard in depth or intro

```
http://proguard.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html
```

what Shrinking in proguard ->  Shrinking programs such as ProGuard can analyze bytecode and remove unused classes, fields, and methods.
so from this we can presume that it is removing your objects since it's not used by anywhere...

so wt you probably need?
you need to stop proguard from shirking that methods or objects from process
so this is the line for that..:
`-keep class com.j256.**<br>
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }<br>
-keep enum com.j256.**<br>
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }<br>
-keep interface com.j256.**<br>
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }`


this line will keep proguard from removing my public methods and variables..
`-keepclassmembers class classpath.** {
  public *;
}`

you need to write column name for atlest id... because it will search for it and will proguard change it's name... so you need to define column name id for primary key..